# 'RANGE BETWEEN ' problems with PARTITION BY when using SparkSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, apache-spark-sql, hive

I have this complicated query when I'm trying to use `PARTITION BY`  in sparkSQL:

For each current row, use `user_id,product_id,[create_date-3day,create_date+3day]` as a data window, to do some data querying( `LAST_VALUE()` for example ). One key part is when querying, I need to do a further sort by column `ORDER BY NEW_DATE` so I can make sure the data in each window are sort by New_date -- which is the real column what I want for querying.

So at first my idea is using such clause, which looks like this :

`LAST_VALUE() over(PARTITION BY user_id,product_id ORDER BY create_date RANGE BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND 3 FOLLOWING)`

Using range between combing with `ORDER BY` should work. But here order by is used combined with range between to do filtering in a window. I need a further ORDER BY to achieve `ORDER BY NEW_DATE`.

But such query doesn't work:

`LAST_VALUE() over(PARTITION BY user_id,product_id ORDER BY create_date RANGE BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND 3 FOLLOWING ORDER BY NEW_DATE)`

Using two orderby in this clause won't compile. How can I further achieve this? Or is there an alternative way to achieve this?

Comment: Could you edit your question and add some simple data and the expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`model`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dwhsg/sql-modeling-data-warehouses.html) clause to define different calculation contexts for window and calculation.

See code below

> ```
> SQL> select *
>   2  from t
>   3  model
>   4    /*Partition by as in window spec*/
>   5    partition by (user_id, product_id)
>   6    /*Dimension column is what should be used to define window size*/
>   7    dimension by (create_date)
>   8    /*Put original value to use in FIRST_VALUE and ORDER BY column*/
>   9    measures(value_, value_*0 as new_value, new_date)
>  10    rules update (
>  11      new_value[any] = max(value_) keep(dense_rank first order by new_date asc)[
>  12          /*Window size applied to all "measures"
>  13            in the above function, including NEW_DATE*/
>  14          create_date between cv(create_date) - interval '3' day and cv(create_date) + interval '3' day
>  15        ]
>  16    )
>  17  order by 1,2,3 asc
> ```

Which for this sample data:

```
> SQL> create table t(
>   2   user_id number, 
>   3   product_id number, 
>   4   create_date date, 
>   5   new_date date, 
>   6   value_ number
>   7  )
>   8  /
> 
> Table T created.
> 
> SQL> 
> SQL> begin
>   2  Insert into T (USER_ID,PRODUCT_ID,CREATE_DATE,NEW_DATE,VALUE_) values ('0','0',date '2023-12-17',date '2023-12-17','1');
>   3  Insert into T (USER_ID,PRODUCT_ID,CREATE_DATE,NEW_DATE,VALUE_) values ('0','0',date '2023-12-16',date '2023-12-18','2');
>   4  Insert into T (USER_ID,PRODUCT_ID,CREATE_DATE,NEW_DATE,VALUE_) values ('0','0',date '2023-12-15',date '2023-12-15','3');
>   5  Insert into T (USER_ID,PRODUCT_ID,CREATE_DATE,NEW_DATE,VALUE_) values ('0','0',date '2023-12-14',date '2023-12-16','4');
>   6  Insert into T (USER_ID,PRODUCT_ID,CREATE_DATE,NEW_DATE,VALUE_) values ('0','0',date '2023-12-13',date '2023-12-12','5');
>   7  Insert into T (USER_ID,PRODUCT_ID,CREATE_DATE,NEW_DATE,VALUE_) values ('0','0',date '2023-12-12',date '2023-12-14','6');
>   8  Insert into T (USER_ID,PRODUCT_ID,CREATE_DATE,NEW_DATE,VALUE_) values ('0','0',date '2023-12-11',date '2023-12-11','7');
>   9  Insert into T (USER_ID,PRODUCT_ID,CREATE_DATE,NEW_DATE,VALUE_) values ('0','0',date '2023-12-10',date '2023-12-11','8');
>  10  Insert into T (USER_ID,PRODUCT_ID,CREATE_DATE,NEW_DATE,VALUE_) values ('0','0',date '2023-12-09',date '2023-12-14','9');
>  11  Insert into T (USER_ID,PRODUCT_ID,CREATE_DATE,NEW_DATE,VALUE_) values ('0','1',date '2023-12-08',date '2023-12-16','10');
>  12  Insert into T (USER_ID,PRODUCT_ID,CREATE_DATE,NEW_DATE,VALUE_) values ('0','1',date '2023-12-07',date '2023-12-15','11');
>  13  Insert into T (USER_ID,PRODUCT_ID,CREATE_DATE,NEW_DATE,VALUE_) values ('0','1',date '2023-12-06',date '2023-12-14','12');
>  14  Insert into T (USER_ID,PRODUCT_ID,CREATE_DATE,NEW_DATE,VALUE_) values ('0','1',date '2023-12-05',date '2023-12-14','13');
>  15  Insert into T (USER_ID,PRODUCT_ID,CREATE_DATE,NEW_DATE,VALUE_) values ('0','1',date '2023-12-04',date '2023-12-17','14');
>  16  Insert into T (USER_ID,PRODUCT_ID,CREATE_DATE,NEW_DATE,VALUE_) values ('0','1',date '2023-12-03',date '2023-12-18','15');
>  17  Insert into T (USER_ID,PRODUCT_ID,CREATE_DATE,NEW_DATE,VALUE_) values ('0','1',date '2023-12-02',date '2023-12-10','16');
>  18  Insert into T (USER_ID,PRODUCT_ID,CREATE_DATE,NEW_DATE,VALUE_) values ('0','1',date '2023-12-01',date '2023-12-09','17');
>  19  Insert into T (USER_ID,PRODUCT_ID,CREATE_DATE,NEW_DATE,VALUE_) values ('0','1',date '2023-11-30',date '2023-12-11','18');
>  20  Insert into T (USER_ID,PRODUCT_ID,CREATE_DATE,NEW_DATE,VALUE_) values ('0','1',date '2023-11-29',date '2023-12-16','19');
>  21  Insert into T (USER_ID,PRODUCT_ID,CREATE_DATE,NEW_DATE,VALUE_) values ('1','2',date '2023-11-28',date '2023-12-15','20');
>  22  Insert into T (USER_ID,PRODUCT_ID,CREATE_DATE,NEW_DATE,VALUE_) values ('1','2',date '2023-11-27',date '2023-12-14','21');
>  23  Insert into T (USER_ID,PRODUCT_ID,CREATE_DATE,NEW_DATE,VALUE_) values ('1','2',date '2023-11-26',date '2023-12-17','22');
>  24  Insert into T (USER_ID,PRODUCT_ID,CREATE_DATE,NEW_DATE,VALUE_) values ('1','2',date '2023-11-25',date '2023-12-16','23');
>  25  Insert into T (USER_ID,PRODUCT_ID,CREATE_DATE,NEW_DATE,VALUE_) values ('1','2',date '2023-11-24',date '2023-12-11','24');
>  26  Insert into T (USER_ID,PRODUCT_ID,CREATE_DATE,NEW_DATE,VALUE_) values ('1','2',date '2023-11-23',date '2023-12-15','25');
>  27  Insert into T (USER_ID,PRODUCT_ID,CREATE_DATE,NEW_DATE,VALUE_) values ('1','2',date '2023-11-22',date '2023-12-16','26');
>  28  Insert into T (USER_ID,PRODUCT_ID,CREATE_DATE,NEW_DATE,VALUE_) values ('1','2',date '2023-11-21',date '2023-12-10','27');
>  29  Insert into T (USER_ID,PRODUCT_ID,CREATE_DATE,NEW_DATE,VALUE_) values ('1','2',date '2023-11-20',date '2023-12-12','28');
>  30  Insert into T (USER_ID,PRODUCT_ID,CREATE_DATE,NEW_DATE,VALUE_) values ('1','2',date '2023-11-19',date '2023-12-14','29');
>  31  Insert into T (USER_ID,PRODUCT_ID,CREATE_DATE,NEW_DATE,VALUE_) values ('1','3',date '2023-11-18',date '2023-12-11','30');
>  32  commit;
>  33  end;
>  34  /
> 
> PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

returns

```
>    USER_ID PRODUCT_ID CREATE_DATE             VALUE_  NEW_VALUE NEW_DATE           
> ---------- ---------- ------------------- ---------- ---------- -------------------
>          0          0 2023-12-09 00:00:00          9          8 2023-12-14 00:00:00
>          0          0 2023-12-10 00:00:00          8          8 2023-12-11 00:00:00
>          0          0 2023-12-11 00:00:00          7          8 2023-12-11 00:00:00
>          0          0 2023-12-12 00:00:00          6          8 2023-12-14 00:00:00
>          0          0 2023-12-13 00:00:00          5          8 2023-12-12 00:00:00
>          0          0 2023-12-14 00:00:00          4          7 2023-12-16 00:00:00
>          0          0 2023-12-15 00:00:00          3          5 2023-12-15 00:00:00
>          0          0 2023-12-16 00:00:00          2          5 2023-12-18 00:00:00
>          0          0 2023-12-17 00:00:00          1          3 2023-12-17 00:00:00
>          0          1 2023-11-29 00:00:00         19         17 2023-12-16 00:00:00
>          0          1 2023-11-30 00:00:00         18         17 2023-12-11 00:00:00
>          0          1 2023-12-01 00:00:00         17         17 2023-12-09 00:00:00
>          0          1 2023-12-02 00:00:00         16         17 2023-12-10 00:00:00
>          0          1 2023-12-03 00:00:00         15         17 2023-12-18 00:00:00
>          0          1 2023-12-04 00:00:00         14         17 2023-12-17 00:00:00
>          0          1 2023-12-05 00:00:00         13         16 2023-12-14 00:00:00
>          0          1 2023-12-06 00:00:00         12         13 2023-12-14 00:00:00
>          0          1 2023-12-07 00:00:00         11         13 2023-12-15 00:00:00
>          0          1 2023-12-08 00:00:00         10         13 2023-12-16 00:00:00
>          1          2 2023-11-19 00:00:00         29         27 2023-12-14 00:00:00
>          1          2 2023-11-20 00:00:00         28         27 2023-12-12 00:00:00
>          1          2 2023-11-21 00:00:00         27         27 2023-12-10 00:00:00
>          1          2 2023-11-22 00:00:00         26         27 2023-12-16 00:00:00
>          1          2 2023-11-23 00:00:00         25         27 2023-12-15 00:00:00
>          1          2 2023-11-24 00:00:00         24         27 2023-12-11 00:00:00
>          1          2 2023-11-25 00:00:00         23         24 2023-12-16 00:00:00
>          1          2 2023-11-26 00:00:00         22         24 2023-12-17 00:00:00
>          1          2 2023-11-27 00:00:00         21         24 2023-12-14 00:00:00
>          1          2 2023-11-28 00:00:00         20         21 2023-12-15 00:00:00
>          1          3 2023-11-18 00:00:00         30         30 2023-12-11 00:00:00
> 
> 30 rows selected.
```